# Can I pass a value directly in the MVC pattern?

Tags: java

I am studying MVC pattern, which is java jsp model2.

I got the seq value from the Edit.java file.
With this seq value, I'm going to write a `select * from address where seq=?` statement in DAO.

In this case, which of the following statements should be used for Edit.java?

```
AddressDAO dao = new AddressDAO();
AddressDTO dto = new AddressDTO();

//1
dto.setSeq(req.getParameter("seq"));
dao.getToEdit(dto);

//2
dao.getToEdit(req.getParameter("seq"));
```

I wonder if it is possible to directly pass the seq value, which is method 2, to dao, or give a value to dto and pass dto to dao, which is the correct method. I'm also curious as to why.